# angularfire retrieving data timestamp to timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am trying to retrieve data using **angularfire** .I.e retrieve all data in an array from one timestamp to another timestamp.

[image]

```
var messageOfEachUser =firebase.database().ref().child("messages").child(data.key);
var currentTime = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
var query = messageOfEachUser.queryOrderedByChild("time").queryStartingAtValue(currentTime).queryEndingAtValue(lastSeenValueFromNode);

var listOfNewMessages = $firebaseArray(query);
console.log(listOfNewMessages);
```

Here in the above code connection to firebase. And querying data from a currenTime to lastSeenValueFromNode where lastSeenValueFromNode contains a timestamp when a user visited this node last time.

Comment: Can you show us the code of where you are stuck?

Comment: var messageOfEachUser =firebase.database().ref().child("messages").child(data.key);
            var currentTime = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
            var query = messageOfEachUser.queryOrderedByChild("time").queryStartingAtValue(currentTime).queryEndingAtValue(lastSeenValueFromNode);
            var listOfNewMessages = $firebaseArray(query);
            console.log(listOfNewMessages);
Here in the above code connection to firebase. And querying data

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40522288/edit) and include the code there, so that you can format it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot user `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in the way you are doing here. It is really just a marker value, that will be converted into the actual timestamp when your operation reaches the server.

Since you are using timestamps, you can simply use the local time as a rough estimate:

```
var currentTime = Date.now();
```

Alternatively, you can use Firebase's built-in latency detection value and get a value that is closer to `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`:

```
var offsetRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/serverTimeOffset");
offsetRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  var offset = snap.val();
  var currentTime = Date.now() + offset;
});
```